# runtime default values fail equality

Tags: c#, compare, boxing

I want to do some comparing of member properties at runtime but value type prohibits unusual behaviour.

I have something like the following

```
public static object DefaultValue(this Type type) 
{
    return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
}


class ExampleClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public XElement ToXml()
    {
        var srcTree = from prop in GetType().GetProperties()
                      let value = prop.GetValue(foo, null)
                      where value != prop.PropertyType.DefaultValue()
                      select new XElement(prop.Name.ToLower(), value);

                              ...

    }
}
```

if I initialize my object `new ExampleClass()` I find the price with a value of 0. I can confirm `DefaultValue()` returns 0 for the price which is not equal to 0 during equality comparison. Is because now it’s comparing objects or what. What can I achieve the behaviour I want?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? What you've shown us here is your proposed solution to your actual problem.

Comment: Are you trying to write your own serializer?

Comment: Maybe 0 != 0? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940222/how-to-properly-compare-decimal-values-in-c

Comment: `value != prop.PropertyType.DefaultValue()` do reference comparison. Each boxing operation for not nullable value type will return distinct references. You can use [`RuntimeHelpers.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.equals) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object DefaultValue(this Type type)
```

the method returns an object, Although you judge whether it is a value type in the method and use `Activator.CreateInstance` create the type dynamically.

but the value will be boxing in an object be an object type value instead of your expected value type.

When you used  `==` on an expression of type `object`, it'll use `ReferenceEquals` to compare the references instead of value.

```
 var srcTree = from prop in GetType().GetProperties()
                          let value = prop.GetValue(foo, null)
                          where !Equals(value, prop.PropertyType.DefaultValue())
                          select new XElement(prop.Name.ToLower(), value);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ad8VTT)

---

Here is a sample for your case

we can saw `defaultVal` object set a value `0`, which is `int` type (doing boxing).

`dymanicVal` created `int` by `Activator.CreateInstance` method.

Then when we use `==` to compare two objects they will compare their reference instead of `int` value

so you can try to use [Equals](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=object) method to compare the value will call  [RuntimeHelpers.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2) method then compare their value instead of references.

```
object defaultVal = 0;
object dymanicVal = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(int));

Console.WriteLine(Equals(defaultVal, dymanicVal)); //True
Console.WriteLine(defaultVal == dymanicVal);      //false
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MrMT9l)